# How can I assign values to a dataframe with a loop if empty series come up

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am filtering a lot in a bigger Dataframe and putting those results in a new column (different values for each row). Sometimes the filtering end up in an empty Series and I get a "ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series."

Is there a way that in these cases a "Nan" or a "0" is used?

Here is an example of my problem:

```
  df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0,20).reshape(4,5),columns=["A","B","C","D","E"])
    
    for idx in df.index:
         df.loc[idx,"E"]=df.loc[(df.A>10)&(df.B<11)].C.values
```

Expected result here: Nan or 0

Comment: Please post your expected output based on sample input provided.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a slicker way to put this together with `np.where() or apply(lambda x: x....)` but really you just need to test if the returned value is is an empty dataframe/value, and if it is set your column to zero.

```
for idx in df.index:
    if len(df.loc[(df.A>10)&(df.B<11)].C.values)==0:
        df.loc[idx,"E"] = 0
    else:
        df.loc[idx,"E"]=df.loc[(df.A>10)&(df.B<11)].C.values
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to be an option. I tried it so far with a try and except line. That also works but looked unnecesary complicated to me^^. 
I will try if I can make it better with your advice. I did not think about using a lambda function so far but it could work out. So, thank you!